# Can anybody recover pictures or data from a SD Card other than the Owner?

Tags: resolution

I have a Android phone and the SD Card got corrupted. It had pictures of important information and I want to know if someone other than myself can retrieve the pictures or data?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about data recovery, not photography. See https://superuser.com/questions/40058/recover-data-from-sd-card or https://superuser.com/questions/855876/recover-data-from-card-that-cannnot-be-read

Comment: Did you encrypt the SD-Card? If yes, this is somehow related:
https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/32822/is-an-android-encrypted-sdcard-readable-decryptable-easily-by-a-desktop-machine#33800

Answer (score 2):

The card doesn't know or care who owns it.  There certainly are data-retrieval services who manage to rescue other people's cards!